# Jquery Draggable not working on created elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I have a button that when i click on it , it should create a div and place it within a container (Parent div ) and make it Draggable.

The problem that i have included the jquery-ui and the jquery ; but still not working .

here is the peace of code:

```
function perform() {
 $homy= $("<div class='cabine'></div>");
   texty=$("<textarea class='sub' readonly></textarea>");
      $homy.append(texty);
         $homy.draggable();
           $homy.appendTo('#container');
}
```

Comment: give more code if there is any

Comment: @MarcinC. there is nothing else to do in this function ,,
 it's succeeded to add the div into the container , 
but the Draggable part didn't work i don't know why !

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue until I saw this post. Then I knew what was problem was.
The problem is in the applying of the draggable function.

Usually, the draggable function is applied to the elements as soon as document it ready like the code below.

`$('.draggable').draggable();`

This applies the draggable function only for those elements which already exists so it will not work for any element created afterwards.

The solution is to apply the function to the newly created elements too. As soon as the element is created use the same code as above to apply to any newly created element.